glossaries-extra: using both groups and page numbers
I want to combine a typical list of acronyms and a separate grouped list of symbols. After trying several solutions with the base glossaries package, I found that the glossaries-extra offers the option to group entries, which was exactly what I needed.
After half a day of work, I arrived at this MWE that almost works:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[record,symbols,stylemods=longextra]{glossaries-extra}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newnotation}{m m m m m}{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname #1\endcsname}{\gls{#1}}%
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{%
        type=symbols, 
        name=\ensuremath{#2}, 
        sort={#4}, 
        description={#3},
        group={#5}
    }%
}
\renewcommand*{\glslongextraGroupHeading}[2]{%
  \glsxtrgetgrouptitle{#2}{\thisgrptitle}%
  \glslongextraHeaderFmt\thisgrptitle
  \tabularnewline*\noalign{\vskip\normalbaselineskip}%
}

\newacronym{AI}{AI}{artificial intelligence}

\newnotation{epsi}{\epsilon}{A very small number}{eps}{general}

\newnotation{data}{D}{Dataset}{D}{ml}
\newnotation{sizeD}{N}{Size of dataset}{N}{ml}

\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{general}{General}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{ml}{Machine Learning}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


A dataset $\data$, and its size $\sizeD$.

\printunsrtglossary[type=main,style=list]
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long-name-desc]

\end{document}

Resulting in the output:

The \newnotation command allows me to use the notation naturally in the document.
Sadly, this setup does not show the page numbers, which is related to what Nicola Talbot discussed here:
glossaries-extra not displaying page numbers
In my case the use of the record package option, which I am using to be able to use the groups, necessitates the use of \printunsrtglossary
Is there a way to save my solution using glossaries-extra, or do I have to find another way to define groups?

Welcome! It isn't the groups so much as the unsorted part which is problematic, if I understand the linked answer correctly.

Correct, the problem is slightly different. I clarified the question. Since I use the record option, I also have to use \printunsrtglossary, which as she says is not showing page numbers.

Given the author of the package says this can't be done, your choice is likely to be either accepting that limitation or rewriting part of the package's internals. If there was a simple fix, Nicola should know.

In that case, I am open to the most elegant solution on how to do grouped glossaries in LaTeX. This could also be helpful for any other person encountering this problem.

Hmm. I've always used type but that's for actual glossaries rather than symbols. I guess if you need glossaries too that would get complicated. (You don't say whether you need glossaries, too, so I don't know if that's a consideration.)

Indeed, I have one glossary for abbreviations, which is set in a typical list style. Then I want to group the mathematical notation by topic.

Hmm. So you could, in that case, just make them all regular glossaries and impose a suitable style. Then you use type for the groups, maybe? I don't usually print page numbers anyway, but i don't see why it wouldn't work, and you'd only have to pull out the abbreviations to do separately?
